# How to find the layout type in android Recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am using `Recyclerview` to display a list of item in my android application. I am giving the option for the user to switch between list and grid. That is working fine but the grid layout is fine but for list it is not good.

I want to use different layout when the user is switched to List. Please any one tell me how I can achieve that from `Recyclerview`.

FYI :- I am using `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);` to switch between grid and list

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag in your adapter and notify the adapter to update the view when you change your `LayoutDataManager`.

```
private static final int TYPE_LINEAR = 0;
private static final int TYPE_GRID = 1;

private int type;

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return type;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_LINEAR:
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_linear), null);
        case TYPE_GRID:
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid), null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you help me how to set type in Activity

Comment: Just add the code above to your adapter and call `adapter.setType(TYPE_YOU_WANT);` together with `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);`

Comment: I am done with the changes but I am not able to get the type in adapter :(

Comment: add a method `public int getType(){ return type; }` then